# How would I start an attempt at solving this differential equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation is:

${dP\over dT}=kP\Bigl(1-{P\over M}\Bigr)-\alpha P$

where $k > 0, \space M > 0$ and $\alpha > 0$ are constants.

How would I start an approach to solving this differential equation?

Comment: **Hint:** It is a Separable Equation, so separate and integrate. I am pretty sure this same question has been asked a few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a version of
$y' = ay^2+by
$.
This can be written as
$\dfrac{dy}{ay^2+by}
=dx$.

Since
$\dfrac1{ay^2+by}
=\dfrac1{by}-\dfrac{a}{b(ay+b)}
$,
$\int\dfrac{dy}{ay^2+by}
= \dfrac{\ln(y) - \ln(a y + b)}{b}
$
so,
letting $c$ be the
constant of integration,
$x
=\dfrac{\ln(y) - \ln(a y + b)}{b}+c
$
or
$bx-bc
=\ln(y) - \ln(a y + b)
=\ln(y/(a y + b))
$
or
$e^{-bx+bc}
=\dfrac{ay+b}{y}
=a+\dfrac{b}{y}
$
or
$e^{-bx+bc}-a
=\dfrac{b}{y}
$
or
$y
=\dfrac{b}{e^{-bx+bc}-a}
$.

Looks like a version 
of the logistic curve.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in comment and answer, rewrite $${dP\over dT}=kP\Bigl(1-{P\over M}\Bigr)-\alpha P$$ as
$${dT\over dP}=\frac 1{kP\Bigl(1-{P\over M}\Bigr)-\alpha P}=\frac 1 { P (k-\alpha )-\frac{k }{M}P^2}=\frac 1{P\Bigl(k-\alpha-\frac{k }{M}P\Bigr)}=\frac{\frac M k } {P \Bigl(\frac{M(k-\alpha)}k-P\Bigr)}$$ For more legibility, let $a=\frac M k$ and $b=\frac{M(k-\alpha)}k$ to make 
$${dT\over dP}=\frac a {P(b-P)}$$
  and use partial fraction decomposition to get 
$${dT\over dP}=\frac{a}{b P}-\frac{a}{b (P-b)}\implies \frac b a\,{dT\over dP}=\frac{1}{P}-\frac{1}{P-b}$$ Now, integrate both sides
$$\frac b a T+c_1=\log \left(\frac{P}{P-b}\right)\implies \frac{P}{P-b}=c_2\,e^{\frac{b }{a}T}\implies P=\frac{b \,c_2\, e^{\frac{b }{a}T}}{c_2\, e^{\frac{b }{a}T}-1}$$ what you can further simplify as 
$$P=\frac{b}{1-c_3\,e^{-\frac{b }{a}T}}$$ Replace $a,b$ by their definition and compute $c_3$ from the initial condition.